# How to evaluate a responsive but unknown network protocol?

Tags: network, nmap, ports, network-scanners, protocols

I am studying CREST CPSA where the syllabus is listed [here](https://www.crest-approved.org/wp-content/uploads/crest-crt-cpsa-technical-syllabus-2.4.pdf).

There is a part of the syllabus which states I should know the `Evaluation of responsive but unknown network applications`.

I find this interesting, as with my limited experience in penetration testing thus far, every nmap scan I have done has been a well-known port number, there has been a service name attached such as Apache (with, or without, a version number), and failing that I have used a tool like telnet to connect to the port to read banner information.

I was curious if, at this basic level, there are any other approaches that one could take to identify responsive yet unknown network applications?